# Value of textbox has changed but aspx page don't update

Tags: asp.net, variables, edit

I'm newbie to asp.net, and I've a question. I load for update an aspx page, using querystring, like `edit.aspx?Id=123`. In the Load event I read the querystring and load the correct record. Through a button, I'd update the record, so I assign to a variables the new values of textboxes, but I don't understand why the new textbox's value aren't considered. I assign value in this manner (e.g. new_email = txemail.text) but system assign at new_email variable the same value of edited record.
Could someone help me understand what I am making wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share some code for the reference to this issue.

Comment: Without seeing your code i'm guessing that you are overwriting data in the PostBack. Use `if (!IsPostBack) { //bind all data }`

Comment: Excuse me, I try to add some code, but my comment will be too long. I try to understand how can I do.

Comment: you have option to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code, it's possible that I make errors about postback, isn't so clear for me. In any case, I've tried in the updateRecord void, both (!IsPostBack) or (IsPostBack), but in any case variables don't get the updated value.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check if querystring has value
        if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
        {
            int idUser = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
            loadRecord(idUser);
        }
    }



protected void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // update record, deliberately simply, just for test purposes
            int idUser = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
            updateRecord(idUser);

        }

  private void updateRecord (int idRecord)
    {
        string new_FirstName = string.Empty;
        string new_LastName = string.Empty;
        string new_Email = string.Empty;

        try
        {  
            if(IsPostBack)
            {
                new_FirstName = txFirstName.Text;
                new_LastName = txLastName.Text;
                new_Email = txEmailAddr.Text;
            }


            using (AddressBookEntities abe = new AddressBookEntities())
            {
                User updateUser = (from user in abe.Users
                           where user.IdUser == idRecord
                           select user).FirstOrDefault();

                updateUser.FirstName = new_FirstName;
                updateUser.LastName = new_LastName;
                updateUser.Email = new_Email;

                abe.SaveChanges();                    

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```